# Listing directories in c++ under windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, directory, listings

I want to list all files of the current directory, so I have this code :

```
int WLoader::listdir(void)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
    std::wstring path(L"*");
    std::wstring *name;
    HANDLE hFile = FindFirstFile(path.c_str(), &data);

    if  (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
       return (-1);

    while(FindNextFile(hFile, &data) != 0 || GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
    {
        std::cout << data.cFileName << std::endl;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

For unknown reasons, my program is displaying this result :

```
0029F29C
0029F29C
0029F29C
0029F29C
0029F29C
0029F29C
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: It appears to be outputting the cFileName element's address pointer instead of the string it contains.  Have you tried just using printf() instead?

Comment: yeah it works with printf, but i need to have cFileName into a string, because i need it to open a dll. so i think if i can't write the right name of the file, i can't have the right name into a string.

Comment: @NickShaw: That's a terrible idea. There's clearly something up with what he's trying to stream; reverting to the stone-age only possibly _masks_ that problem, and possibly makes it worse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The `WIN32_FIND_DATA` structure's member `cFileName` is a `TCHAR[N]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and [`TCHAR` is a Windows type alias that maps either to `char` or `wchar_t`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc842072.aspx) Problem is, *you don't know which one it will be* when you write your code.

Depending on your build settings, you either have a `char*`, or a `wchar_t*`; one should be used with `std::cout` and the other must be used with `std::wcout`. But which one do you use?!

Fortunately, there's a macro to find out which is in use when you compile:

```
while(FindNextFile(hFile, &data) != 0 || GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) {
#ifdef UNICODE
   std::wcout << data.cFileName << std::endl;
#else
   std::cout << data.cFileName << std::endl;
#endif
}
```

You're going to find the same problem if you try to assign the filename to a `std::string`/`std::wstring`. That's what you get for using the Windows API. :)

---

One way around this is to define macros for the output stream and for strings.

So, somewhere at the top of your program:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define STDCOUT std::wcout
#define STDSTR  std::wstring
#else
#define STDCOUT std::cout
#define STDSTR  std::string
#endif
```

Then in your function, all you need is:

```
while(FindNextFile(hFile, &data) != 0 || GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) {
   STDCOUT << data.cFileName << std::endl;
}
```

and you can use `STDSTR` elsewhere.

Something to consider.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `std::cout` to output a wide-character string. Use `std::wcout` instead.

Comment: and if i want to put cFileName into a string ?

Comment: @Yumino You are already using `std::wstring` for the path, continue using that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: And then when he turns `UNICODE` off, he's got the same problem again.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal In Windows programming `UNICODE` is something that you turn on and then never turn off. Trying to write code that works with `UNICODE` either on or off makes life needlessly difficult.

Comment: @David: I suppose it's more pertinent if your code includes an abstraction layer for later portability. Fat chance with this OP's code. Still, it's worth him _knowing_, surely?

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal I know where you are coming from but `#ifdef UNICODE`, `TCHAR` etc. is not portable one little bit!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: How so? `TCHAR` no, but `UNICODE` is, because you can simply define it yourself to control your abstraction layer's use of `cout`/`wcout`. No?

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal I just don't think it's that simple. What about UTF8 on Linux? Where does that fit into things?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Specific encodings are orthogonal to this; I'm talking about providing support for use of `wcout`/`wstring` with Windows apps in "`UNICODE` mode", without tying your hands if you want to chuck your abstraction onto an environment where you want to use `cout`/`string`. If you're building an actual encoding on top of that (remember, `UNICODE` isn't Unicode _per se_, but just wider characters) then certainly all bets are off!

Answer (score 1):

I expect you have a Unicode/ANSI mismatch. To print a Unicode string, use `std::wcout`